# Robotium setUp() and tearDown() methods

Tags: unit-testing, robotium

I  have a test class as follows. The methods setUp() and tearDown() run before and after each test case. However, I want these methods to run once in the beginning of the test suite and in the end. I could not find an annotation like @BeforeClass, @AfterClass. How can I make these methods to run before the first test case and after the last test case in a test class?

```
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
    }

    public void test1{
    do smt
    }

    public void test2{
    do smt
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The tearUp() method should be placed at the bottom, after your test cases. The tearDown() method will automatically be run last.

The setUp() method should be placed before your test cases and it will automatically be run first before your test cases start running.

Like this:

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
super.setUp();
solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

public void test1{
    do smt
}

public void test2{
    do smt
} 

protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
solo.finishOpenedActivities();
super.tearDown();
}
```